# cardano-cli transaction build-raw error

Tags: cardano-cli, native-assets, token

I've minted 1,000,000,000,000,000 SLIME coin following this guide https://developers.cardano.org/docs/native-tokens/minting/#prerequisites but I'm getting an error at the "Sending tokens to a wallet" section. I've attached a screenshot of all the steps I take along with the error I receive:

Command failed: transaction submit  Error: Error while submitting tx: ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraAlonzo (ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (ValueNotConservedUTxO (Value 4818307 (fromList [(PolicyID {policyID = ScriptHash "5b314f4ac2716a22741a69c2c213ba515d0d90e5e7c8400474b948ee"},fromList [("SLIME",1000000000000000)])])) (Value 7818307 (fromList [(PolicyID {policyID = ScriptHash "5b314f4ac2716a22741a69c2c213ba515d0d90e5e7c8400474b948ee"},fromList [("SLIME",1000000000000000)])])))))])

The variable "address" is set to my address which I'm trying to send SLIME from, and the variable "receiver" is set to the address I'm trying to send SLIME to.

I greatly appreciate help in solving this headache of a blocker for me, thanks, Myles.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to subtract the fee from `$receiver_output`.

Comment: if you can be more specific, at what step? I tried receiver_output=$(expr $receiver_output - $fee + 2000000) and receiver_output=$(expr $receiver_output - $fee) after output=$(expr $funds - $fee - 2000000) and still get the same error: Command failed: transaction submit  Error: Error while submitting tx: ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraAlonzo (ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (ValueNotConservedUTxO (Value 4818307 (fromList [(PolicyID {policyID = ScriptHash "5b314f4ac2716a22741a69c2c213ba515d0d90e5e7c8400474b948ee"},fromList [("SLIME",100000000000000 ...

Comment: In your final build-raw you need something like (($receiver-output - $fee))

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding $receiver-output to the --tx-out line where you are minting the tokens? You are not consuming that UTxO, just ignore that UTxO and the 5000000 lovelaces at that address.

Comment: receiver_output is balance of utxo spent in txin.